# How to make gold effect text using CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my heading text in my webpage like a gold I don' want a color like this `#ffd700` I want the same look and feel like any graphics designer can make gold effect in Photoshop. Here I am attaching an example how I want.
[image: Gold text example]

Comment: You know that Photoshop and CSS are two completely different things? Such kind of effects will not be possible with CSS.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @UweAllner yes I know both are different as I think it is possible somehow in CSS3.

Comment: Almost valid question. But, it is ambiguous, because every designer/man imagines and does things different. So, please provide some image that shows what exactly do you mean by gold text. Ie. someone imagines "outline lens", someone imagines gradient from top to bottom...

Comment: @Miro I have updated my question. Thanks for notify me.

Comment: How about trying from google first? For example searching with phrase 'css gold text' gets you far. Here's one using gradient background and clipping http://www.guestandguest.com/blog/posts/beautiful-gold-text-using-only-css. If you wish to have that drop shadow/"3D" effect also, just play around with text-shadow.

Comment: @mMoovs - Thanks, and here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqfpcn3o/) based on that article. The trick here is the property: `-webkit-background-clip: text`

Comment: @jbutler483 Oh you're right. I didn't notice that the example text was an image on the page I linked...

Comment: @mMoovs: Your example document is fine - the code there works for webkit browsers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `svg` to get effect

Online gradient generator for `svg` - http://10k.aneventapart.com/1/Uploads/319/

```css
svg {
  text-shadow: -1px 0px 1px rgb(97, 100, 5);
}
```

```html
<svg width="550" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad2" y2="1" x2="1" id="g" x1="1" y1="0.1433">
      <stop stop-color="rgb(255, 213, 127)" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="rgb(179, 149, 0)" offset="0.4817" />
      <stop stop-color="rgb(179, 149, 0)" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text font-family="arial" font-size="40" id="svg_1" y="45" x="288" fill="url(#grad2)" font-weight="bold">
    <tspan x="10" y="45">JANDUS TECHNOLOGIES</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know you want to use CSS3 but as you mentioned HTML5 I'd like to post a canvas alternative here. You'll get better browser support if you use a canvas element. The canvas 2D API has a method called [createLinearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) to apply a color gradient to a text by using different color stops:

```
var c = document.getElementById("stage");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "30px Arial";
/* Color gradient */
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 30, 0, 10);
gradient.addColorStop("0", "#a68841");
gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "#5a4917");
gradient.addColorStop("0.6", "#836A28");
gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "#E9D07C");
/* Text shadow */
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1; 
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1; 
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillText("JANDUS TECHNOLOGIES", 0, 30);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2ey8jf3/)

You can also easily apply other effects such as text-shadows.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've made an example using gradient and shadow. Here's HTML code:

```
<div class="block">
  <p class="golden-base golden3">Golden Text</p>
  <p class="golden-base golden1">Using Only CSS</p>
  <p class="golden-base golden2">NO JavaScript!</p>
<div>
```

Here's CSS:

```
.block {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.golden-base {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight:bold;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0.3em; 
  -webkit-margin-after: 0.2em;
}
.golden1 {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF65C, #3A2C00);
  text-shadow: -0.02em -0.03em 0.005em rgba(255, 223, 0, 0.60);
}
.golden2 {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#E8D800, #E0CF00 52%, #A86800 55%, #A86800 );
  text-shadow: -0.02em -0.03em 0.005em rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.56);
}
.golden3 {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF65C 45%, #9A8000 75%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09),
    -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 220, 0, 0.670);
  font-size:2em;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: golden text using css only]

I'm not a designer. So it's hard for me to adjust colors for your needs. However, you may test it and adjust [here @ codepen - link](http://codepen.io/kravemir/pen/azeErJ)

**Disclaimer:** I have tested it only with Google Chrome. To make it working with different browsers you have to port `-webkit-tricks-...`, if possible.

**Edit** based on comments, and more gradient effects.

Comment: You would duplicate the text multiple times? As well as include inline styling?

Comment: @jbutler483 In production: no. Sandbox: depends. Examples: yes - makes easier to understand.

Comment: In Production: no. Sandbox: no. Examples:no - makes new developers think this is ok

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**

---

This is only available (at present) in webkit browsers

---

You could use the

```
 -webkit-background-clip
```

property to get your desired outcome.

A sample would be:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
.gradient {
  font-size: 64px;
  background: linear-gradient(#00AC97 50%, #E4CDA4 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <span class="gradient">Cross browser? Not yet...</span>
</div>
```

In order for this to 'work' in a more cross browser way, I (for once) would have to suggest using an image for this one :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for css text gold gradient:

```
background: #FECA00;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FECA00 38%, #D07800 74%, #FF9300 91%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FECA00 38%, #D07800 74%, #FF9300 91%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FECA00 38%, #D07800 74%, #FF9300 91%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Result:

[image]

or if you wanna explore another orientation you can check in [css text gradient generator](https://www.cssportal.com/css-text-gradient-generator/)

Answer (score 0):

Use text-shadow property in css3 to get the gold effect you need. Refer http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/ for the best result.

Comment: Thanks for helping me dear, but I want to write code manually.